# Looking for some tips to optimize my WebGL 3D Engine

Tags: performance, webgl

I finished Learningwebgl.com and Mozilla tutorials, everything look good at first, but...

Unfortunately, My first engine slow-down after making lots of functions and also separating scripts into pieces (like core.js, math.js, mesh.js and so on), so I get into this performance issues.

Now it takes few seconds to load page on LocalHost (which is quite fast), and also few more seconds to load textures and meshes, and Chrome freeze down after refreshing page for a few times, CPU/GPU usage is abnormal, and even my 'WampServer' crash down!

I'm not Javascript master, but this thing (webgl) looks very sensitive and easily broken down by any mistake, I make Online Painting application with Canvas2D and never had similar issues.

I notice performance is much higher when I put all the scripts into single HTML or JS file than lots of small scripts, maybe that's the issue?

Note: I'm not using jQuery or any additional libraries. (only glMatrix and RequestAnimationFrame scripts)

Question: Please give me some tips before re-writing my engine from ground up, I don't want to do same mistakes!!

Sorry for language

Comment: yes, putting all js in one file seam to be best practice, though use tools that will generate js file for you, so you can still enjoy goodies of separate files. Also do not use enclosures.

Comment: And judging from you description of problem its more JS problems than WebGL :|. Chrome have known issues with large textures (its slow on Chrome). There also may be limit of concurrent conections browser can make, so maybe its another bottleneck?

Answer (score 5):

I've found one good speech about WebGL optimizations. Hope it will be usefull:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfQ8rKGTVlg

There is quite impressive section on how to improve WebGL performance.